# Python script in Qgis for hundreds of texts replaces or gigant 'replace'+'case then else' combined expression?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, sql

I want to replace a text from one collumn into another text in a different collumn and base the condition on two different input collumn/fields.

Collumn 1: Integers (from 1 to 10)

Collumn 2: 100 different combinations of this text type - '1 and 10'

New collumn:

> When appears '10' on collumn1 and '1 and 10' on collumn2 replace with
>   'YPC5' AND ( other example) when appears '1' substitute by 'YPC5' and when appears '10' substitute for 'YPC8', becoming: 'YPC5 and
>   YPC8'. But, if the field1 changes for '9' then 'YPC5 and YPC7'.

[image]

Is there a python script for doing this in a easier way than use a gigant 'replace(' and 'case then else' combined expression?

[image]

Comment: Your question (which you posted a duplicate of today) is difficult to understand. For example you say "Collumn 1: 100 different combinations of this text type - '1 and 10'" then show a screenshot of column 1 where no cell has the value '1 and 10'. Try to edit this question instead to make it understandable and delete your duplicate post from today.

Comment: is shapefile column 1, not matrix column 1. look at the matrix: when shapefile column 1 is equal 10, '1' will be replaced by 'YC1' and '10' by 'YC11'. So, for a shapefile column 2 with this string " 1 plus 10" i want to have this "YC1 plus YC11", and this replacement to be made ona  anew field (called it shapefile column 3).

Comment: Ok. So when you say "When appears '10' on collumn1 and '1 and 10' on collumn2" you swapped the columns and actually mean: "When appears '10' on collumn2 and '1 and 10' on collumn1" . You describe the columns as: Collumn 1: 100 different combinations of this text type - '1 and 10' Collumn 2: Integers (from 1 to 10)

Comment: yes, can you help me now? :)

Comment: The only reason you are not getting the answer you are looking for is that you post unclear questions. If it was clear you would get an answer from someone within minutes. What is the third screenshot for? There is no YPC5 etc. in it.

Answer (score 2):

When having a situation like this one, you need to take a look to dictionaries.

```
your_dict = {'1':'YPC5', '2', 'YPC6', '3':'YPC7', ... , old_value: new_value}
```

then when you want to substitute you just need to do:

```
new_value = your_dict[old_value]
```

in your case, you need to go for the value of each cell and do:

```
new_cell = '{} plus {}'.format(your_dict[column], your_dict[row])
```

Comment: Could you just build a bit of the script since i'm newbie in python, just started learning now..

This is the matrix with replacements to be made:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBfa9.png

Comment: In the second matrix it was a pure substitution, "[value of row substituted] plus [value of col substituted]". Now it's different. I can think of nested dictionaries, where from each key of the first dictionary (dict for rows) contains a second dictionary with all the possible values for the columns.

Comment: Can we chat please?